# How to prevent LWC Wire from loading data automatically?

Tags: lightning-web-components

I would like to prevent the `@wire` function from loading automatically on initialization and instead load it on command.

Currently I am using `refreshApex()` now to load it on command, but I don't want to load it until a button triggers it to load.

The purpose of my question is to add a `Sync` button which load a good amount of data on click only.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't call it via the wire service. Call the Apex method imperatively in your button's onclick handler.

Comment: Suggesting an alternative like this is a good thing to do. Of course, depending on the wire (e.g. if it is a built-in Salesforce wire service) you may not be able to call it imperatively.

Comment: Valid point, @PhilW!

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I needed!

For my case I also added `cachable = false` to the apex method

Answer (score 5):

Wire methods with reactive properties don't call Apex until their reactive values are set to any value other than `undefined`. In other words, if you do this:

```
someProperty;
@wire(someMethod, { someProperty: '$someProperty' }) someWireProperty;
handleClick() {
  this.someProperty = someNonUndefinedValue;
}
```

It won't call the Apex method until the parameters have definition.

Note that if you have a handler instead of a property, it'll still call the method once to set the default object (`{ data: undefined, error: undefined }`).

Comment: Wire doesn't get called until referenced properties are `undefined`. It will get called as soon as they have some values other than `undefined` including `null`. I think your statement is other way around?

Comment: @RahulGawale I see the wording is confusing. I did say "non-`undefined`" (as in, not undefined). I'll clarify.

Comment: Does it start automatically perhaps because I am using an `@api` defined variable? I don't even know why I am using this in the first place